# Multiple Jobs Deployment in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines, azure-webjobssdk

I have a VS solution with multiple projects, each project is an independent WebJob which I am hosting in a Single AppServices. I am trying to automate this to Continuous deployment.What would be the best strategy to deploy only job in the solution which is changed? Is there a way to find out the project which is changed as part of the merge to CI? We are using git and this solution is in a single repository. We are using azure-webjobsdk for the projects.

Comment: What's your VSTS build definition now? Do you use Azure App Service Deploy task to deploy web jobs now?

Comment: I don't have one now, can I deploy multiple webjobs from a single solution with App Service Deploy task.

Comment: No, you can only deploy one webjob by a App Service Deploy task. I added an answer for deployging the changed webjob project, you can have a try.

Comment: facing issue like - deploying multiple webjobs using seperate app service deploy task replacing all the web jobs and can only see last one - please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow below steps to deploy the only changed webjob:

Assume your file structure as below:

```
Git root
   |___WebJob1
          |___WebJob1.sln
          |___webJob1
                 |___WebJob1.csproj
          |___WebJob2
                 |___WebJob2.csproj
          |___ …
          |___WebJobn
                 |___WebJobn.csproj
```

**1. Add a variable** (such as `buildporj` with default value `none`) to record the changed webJob project package.

**2. Add NuGet restore task** for the `WebJob1/WebJob1.sln`.

**3. Add Visual studio Build task** with the MSBuild arguments:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(Build.BinariesDirectory)\\"
```

[image]

**4. Add PowerShell Task** to detect which WebJob project changed and copy the package from `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` by the script as below:

```
$files=$(git diff HEAD HEAD~ --name-only)
echo "changed files: $files"
for ($i=0;$i -lt $files.Length; $i++)
{
  $file=$files[$i] -split '/'
  $files[$i]=$file[1]
}
$uni=$files | Get-Unique

$uni=@($uni | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch ".sln"})
echo "You changed the project (if more than one projects were changed, only deploy the first one): $uni"
$proj=$uni[0]+".zip"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildproj;]$proj"
Copy-Item $(Build.BinariesDirectory)\$proj $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

5. **Add Azure App Service Deploy task** by specifing the Package or folder option as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\**\$(buildproj)`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can have different WebJobs project(WebJob1.csproj, WebJob2.csproj) in a single solution and you can deploy using single build and release pipeline. All you need to do is :-

In your build solution step define:-

1. Visual Studio Build (Solution: ***.sln, MSBuild Arguments:
       /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package
       /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true
       /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\")
2. Publish Build Artifacts (Path to Publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory); Artifact Name:  drop; Artifact Type: Server)

Create a release definition for this build definition and add a task

1. Azure App Service Deploy
2. Select your Azure Subscription and App Service name;
3. Select your Package or Folder:
   $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)**\WebJob1.zip

You can similary create another Azure App Service Deploy task for WebJob2.zip and deploy as many webjobs you want through a single build and release pipeline.

Comment: Deploying multiple jobs replacing all existing and last one is only present. help

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Only the last web job is deployed..