# Wildcards in VSTS Release Definition

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to deploy Webjobs(4 of them) to App service, but while deploying them I am getting error -

```
2017-12-11T11:44:09 ==============================================================================
2017-12-11T11:44:10 Got connection details for Azure App 
Service:'**********'
2017-12-11T11:44:10 ##[error]Error: More than one package 
matched with specified pattern. Please restrain the search 
pattern.
2017-12-11T11:44:13 Successfully updated deployment History 
at ***********
2017-12-11T11:44:13 ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Azure Webjob
```

Below is the configuration screen :-
[image: Configuration]

Any idea how can I deploy all webjobs from single task instead of making multiple tasks?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. If you look at the source code (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment/azurermwebappdeployment.ts#L97) this task expects a single package, not a list of packages.

Comment: But we can use wildcards so in case of multiple zip files it should take all

Comment: No, you can use wildcards so you don't have to specify the exact path to your .zip file. The wild cards aren't meant for selecting multiple files. The default value $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip means that it searches for a zip file somewhere nested in your DefaultWorkingDirectory

Comment: I see, then creating a job using power shell would be a better approach..!!

Comment: Or just use the same task 4 times.

Comment: Thank you @WouterdeKort and Daniel for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure App Deploy task does take wild cards but this doesn't mean it can deploy multiple packages. The wild cards are used to search for a Web Deploy Package in multiple folders.

The default value is `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/*.zip`. This means that the task will search for a .zip file somewhere beneath your `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`.

If you look at the code for the App Deploy Task (Yes! It's [open source on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment/azurermwebappdeployment.ts#L97)) you see the check for only one matching file:

```
 if(availableWebPackages.length > 1) {
      throw new Error(tl.loc('MorethanonepackagematchedwithspecifiedpatternPleaserestrainthesearchpattern'));
 }
 webDeployPkg = availableWebPackages[0];
```

To deploy multiple Web Deployment Packages, the easiest is to clone the task and make sure that each search pattern matches a single Web Deploy Package. You would then end up with four tasks.

*Or you send a pull request on GitHub to extend the task to deploy multiple packages at once.*

Answer (score 1):

For Azure App Service Deploy task, it can only deploy one webjob.

Since you have four webjobs, you should make sure the wildcards for the package should only match a unique webjob.

- If you want to deploy all the four webjobs, you can use four Azure App Service Deploy tasks (as Daniel mentioned), and make sure each task only match one webjob.
- If you want to deploy only one webjob which is changed, you can detect the changed wenjob and deploy for it. Detail steps, you can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695205/multiple-jobs-deployment-in-visual-studio-team-services/47710965#47710965).