# How to deploy multiple .net core webjob in a single app service using azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs, .net-core-3.1

I have 2 .NET Core 3.1 WebJob in a single solution.
I am able to build each of the Webjobs and created the .zip files for each job in which the folder structure is in the below format :

> TestJob_1.zip **---** App_Data\jobs\continuous\TestJob_1

> TestJob_2.zip **---** App_Data\jobs\continuous\TestJob_2

Now, in order to deploy both of my webjob, I have added 2 "Azure App Service Task", pointing to same App Service, and given the folder location as below for each of my webjobs repectively.

[image]

Now, if I run my Release pipeline, all my tasks are successfully completed. And when I checked in my App Service, I see only the TestJob_2 is published.

And after these, I disabled the task related to TestJob_2 webjob and run the pipeline only with the task for TestJob_1, and now when I checked, TestJob_2 webjob is replaced by TestJob_1 webjob & I can able to see TestJob_1 but not TestJob_2.

Please help me here.

Comment: I think PatrickLu-MSFT's answer in another post will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049633/deploying-multiple-webjobs-from-the-same-project-in-a-azure-devops-release-defin

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to associate webjobs with web app, by right clicking your
   Web App project in Visual Studio and select **Add** > **Existing Project
   as Azure WebJob** and follow the wizard.
2. The webjobS are included in the web app package, then you just need
   to deploy web app to azure app service.
3. It will generate webjob’s package too during publishing (that why
   there are two zip files), but you just need to specify web app
   package in Azure App Service deploy task. (Check Publish using Web
   Deploy option). Make sure the "Exclude files from the App_data
   folder" is unchecked:

[image]

For details , you can check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50045752/how-do-you-deploy-an-azure-webjob-and-app-to-the-same-app-service-via-vsts).

Comment: @Sheegy did this work?