# Azure (release pipeline) web job different names same app service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using azure release pipeline, I am trying to deploy **same web job** with **different names** (as per stage) within **same app service**. Steps that I follow (created a group task to repeat same steps in each stage) are:

1. Copy ArtifactPath/triggered/SampleWebJob to ArtifactPath/triggered/SampleWebJob_stage **for instance, SampleWebJob_dev
2. Delete original files and folder i.e SampleWebJob
3. Deploy using azure app service deploy step

**Problem**

> Next stage overwrites the web job deployed in previous stages.

For example, **dev** stage creates a  new webjob SampleWebJob_dev but when **test** stage runs (manually), SampleWebJob_dev gets replaced by SampleWebJob_test.

*How to keep both webjobs in same app service?*

Comment: This SO thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860046/how-to-deploy-multiple-net-core-webjob-in-a-single-app-service-using-azure-devo will help resolve the issue.

Comment: @RajkumarMamidiChettu-MT thread that you referred is about having two web job in one app service. My scenario is to deploy same web job with multiple names (_dev, _test) in same app service.