# Deploying multiple Web job on same app service using pipeline , replacing all with last one

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs, azure-cloud-services, azure-webjobs-continuous

build artifacts contains separate folders for both the web jobs and included into the release pipelines.
When trying to deploy then on same app service using pipeline actually replacing all existing with the last web job deployed.
Tasks for both job deployments are success.

any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47695205/multiple-jobs-deployment-in-visual-studio-team-services) you can refer to .

Comment: in my case - having two separate web job projects,deploying with separate appservice deploy task. When second jobs task executes (joblocationas  - app_Data/jobs/continuous/job2) is only available there

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

In "Azure App Service deploy" task, under "Additional Deployment Options", select "Web Deploy" as "Deployment method".